# Two commuting matrices over a commutative ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

I would like to know if there are results about the dimension of the Algebra generated by two commuting Matrices over a ring (as there are in the case of a Field).
The good news is that "my" ring is commutative, the bad news is that it is not a domain of integrity.
Thanks for your help

Comment: If your ring is reduced, it embeds in a product of domains. In any case, it would be interesting to inspect the ring of quotients of your ring.

Comment: You should be more precise in what you want to call "dimension".

Comment: More precise:I know the case of a field and results by Gerstenhaber, etc..., who proves that the Algebra generated by two commuting matrices (nxn rows and columns) is not greater than n; is it true when the matrices of their coefficients in a ring (not embeddeable (?) in a field ?